# Uninstall Podcasts app?

Tags: podcast, system-apps

It appears that, for some strange reason, the Podcasts app is OS-level, and so I cannot uninstall that. Yet, I can uninstall the Transfer My Data app (provided I set the year to something like 2113), which, to me, is more essential than podcasts (which I couldn't care less for).

Is there any workaround here?

Running Denim on a Lumia 520.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known way to uninstall the Podcasts app. If I remember correctly, Transfer My Data is not an OS app; you install it from the Store, so there is a difference there.

Comment: The Transfer my Data app is also exclusive to Lumia phones, ant not available for other vendors (like HTC)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Transfer My Data did come with the phone, though.

Comment: Was the phone brand new?

Comment: I know this is super-delayed, but yes, it was brand new, out of the box. I have since upgraded to another device without the app installed, so it may have been an OEM bundling situation.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be of much help now. You can uninstall the Podcast app on Windows 10 mobile.

Comment: Nope @Kolappan. It cant be uninstall in W10 as well